# How to emulate a BehaviorSubject with a connectable Observable in RX-Scala

Tags: scala, rx-java

Is there a way to make an `Observable` emulate a `BehaviorSubject` (but **without** the `Observer` interface) in rx-scala? I.e. make it an Observable with memory, so that it can have multiple subscriptions, and on each new subscription, it produces the last emitted value?

`Observable.publish()` does half the job, but it doesn't emit the last value. `Observable.cache.publish()` on the other hand replays all values - I would need something like that, but which only replays the last emitted value, to handle infinite streams.

Rx-Java solutions also accepted, although the native Scala form is preferred!

Comment: RxJava already has a `BahaviorSubject` implementation.  Should be straightforward to implement in Scala using the Java version as a template.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I appreciate there is a `BehaviorSubject` in Scala already (see @TheTerribleSwiftTomato answer), but I don't want to use this as it exposes the Observer interface.

Comment: So use a `BehaviorSubject<T>` internally and expose it as an `Observable<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the scala bindings, use `observable replay 1 refCount`.

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using the [existing `BehaviorSubject` Scala implementation](http://rxscala.github.io/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.subjects.BehaviorSubject)? As you can see, it's certainly available in `0.16.0`, and I'm certain `0.15.0` includes it as well.

Comment: Problem with this is that it exposes the Observer interface, which I don't want to do. Also, I haven't figured out how to chain them together nicely - is there a 'monadic' way to do this? i.e. without calling `subscribe`, so _not_ like `obs.subscribe(onNext => subj.onNext(onNext))`?

Comment: @Luciano : err... **all** `Subject`s are both `Observable`s **and** `Observer`s **by definition**, regardless whether you're using Scala or [Java](http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/Subject.html). I guess you could always wrap it in something... Regarding chaining: you can use the `subscribe(observer: Observer[T])` method variant (as to why you're able to do that, see first sentence).

Comment: Yes, I understand a `Subject` is both an `Observable` and and an `Observer`, and that's why I want to avoid using it. It's the reason for my q' - how to turn an observable into something that can have multiple subscriptions which emit the last value on `subscribe()`. Re: chaining, I need it to work the other way around. i.e. _not_ `observable.subscribe(subj)` but `subj.subscribe(observable)`, which doesn't work, because an `Observable` isn't an `Observer`!

Comment: @Luciano: 1. Your original question said **nothing** about avoiding `Observer` (and you give no reason as to why). 2. In the last comment, you asked about "how to chain them together". The context was `BehaviorSubject`s, not `Observable`s. In other words: you've completely changed the requirements of your question(s), so it's no wonder the answers don't satisfy you. Maybe you should try re-asking the question with your **actual**, **precise** requirements and reasons for them (for making it easier to provide a meaningful answer)?